# How can a pointer to an int (array) be copied to an int array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Because you cannot return `int[]` (or any array type for that matter) in c++, I have a function or two which instead return `int*`, which has made my existence rather difficult.

A function of my program requires that an array that I've been passing about between functions be copied and incremented around in various ways, and then the copy returned. The only way I've found to copy the data such that the original array is unaffected by changes in the copy, is copying each "member" at a time, e.g.

```
int* foo(int* a) {
    int b[2] = {a[0], a[1]};
    /* do unspeakable things to b */
    return b;
}
```

Which is fine enough for this very specific case, but I'm sure isn't the most effective method, especially for large arrays.

Is there some type-casting wizardry or other method I can use to do this 
more efficiently?

---

**NOTE:** I'm *not* asking if this is good practice, useful, in line with the Geneva convention, or safe *very intentionally*. I don't particularly care about that information at this moment, and if you absolutely must say it I'd rather it not be the body or opening of your answer.

Also, is the kerning around the T in NOTE super weird for anyone else?

**EDIT:** After actually using my "solution" I determined that I'm an idiot and should test things before spouting off about them.

Comment: "Is there some type-casting wizardry or other method I can use to do this more efficiently?" Use loops? Or `std::memcpy`? Why do you even care about efficiency when you do not want to hear the idiomatic solutions (which are obviously the best ones)? Do you even know if you actually have to copy, which may be inefficient in itself instead of a move? So many questions...

Comment: You can't return a raw array, unfortunately. It decays to a pointer and the array goes out of scope, leaving the pointer pointing at invalid memory. Are you allowed to use `std::array` instead?

Comment: *Also, is the kerning around the T in NOTE super weird for anyone else?* Yep.

Comment: "Which is fine enough for this very specific case," - no it isn't (you return pointer to local array)

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `std::vector<int>`? The vector can be passed into a function as a copy and returned as a copy (or pass the target by reference).

Answer (score 1):

```
int b[2];
int * c = b;
```

From [cppreference implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> Array to pointer conversion
>   An lvalue or rvalue of type "array of N T"
>   or "array of unknown bound of T" can be implicitly converted to a
>   prvalue of type "pointer to T".

That means that any array of type is implicitly converted to a pointer to type. The pointer points to the first member of the array, so `c == &b[0]`. Interestingly, the pointer to array is also equal to the pointer of the first element of the array `&b == &b[0]`, but has a different type, ie:

```
int b[2];
int * c = b; // implicit conversion from array to pointer
int (*d)[2] = &b; // &b is a pointer to an array of 2 ints
int * e = &b[0]; // pointer to the first element
```

The function:

```
int* foo(int* a) {
    int b[2] = {a[0], a[1]};
    /* do unspeakable things to b */
    return b;
}
```

Is very invalid, wrong, confusing and bad. The memory behind `b` is invalid after `}` function returns, so the pointer returned by the function is invalid and cannot be used.

> Because you cannot return int[]

`int[]` is an array of unspecified size, you cannot do anything with it. Note that inside function parameter list `int[]` is implicitly converted into `int*`. So the following are exactly equivalent:

```
void f(int a[]);
void f(int *a);
```

> or any array type for that matter) in c++

You can return `std::array<int , 2>`

```
 std::array<int, 2> f() {
        std::array<int, 2> ret;
        return ret;
 }
```

Note that this is highly inefficient. It needs to return `2 * sizeof(int)` of data, which will get bigger with greater size. Returning a pointer to the first member of the array is only returning the pointer value, needs less space. Also note that `std::array<int, 2> var = f();` will `copy` all array elements between `f()` returned value and `var` (without copy elision), so it's very inefficient.

> I'm sure isn't the most effective method

In terms of speed, initializing each array member explicitly and returning a pointer to the first element of an array is the most efficient method. A proper compiler will generate fast instruction for that. But you say `and then the copy returned` - you have to create a copy in your function of the array, so you have to copy all array members between the original and the copy. There's no other way around.

> Is there some type-casting wizardry or other method I can use to do this more efficiently?

Toss raw C array to the trash bin, and move to containers. Move to `std::array<int, 2>` if you know the size at compile time, and `std::vector<int>` if the size is unknown at compile time.

```
std::vector<int> foo(std::vector<int> a) {
    std::vector<int> b{a};
    return b;
}
```

Note that `return b` is ok here, as the `std::vector<int>` in itself stores a pointer to dynamically allocated memory. Memory allocated with `new` does not  cease to exist after `}`, so you can return a pointer to it. If your compiler supports copy elision, the function should work fast. A faster version would be to use references.

```
 void f(std::vector<int>& ret, std::vector<int> a) {
       ret = a;
 }
```

Comment: And if you are working in `std::array`s (or any other library  container) the problems with assigning pretty much go away. You can pass by value and get a free copy to work on with no extra effort on your part.

Comment: Kamil, you almost have what I was talking about with `std::vector<int> foo(std::vector<int> a) {
    std::vector<int> b{a};
    return b;
}`. You can simplify it to `std::vector<int> foo(std::vector<int> a) {
    return a;
}` because parameter `a` is a copy of the argument used in the call.

Answer (score 0):

You can input both int array into a function and let the function do the copy for you like this:

```
bool CopyIntArray(int* pA, int cA, int* pB, int cB)
{
    if (pA == NULL || cA == 0 || pB == NULL || cB == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cA && i < cB; i++)
    {
        pB[i] = pA[i];
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int x[10] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    int y[10] = { 0 };

    CopyIntArray(x, 10, y, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

by the way

```
int* foo(int* a) {
    int b[2] = {a[0], a[1]};
    /* do unspeakable things to b */
    return b;
}
```

b is destroyed when step out of the function scope, so your app would be dangerous when use a destroyed variable as the function output.